# How to create a navigation stack of views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

In UIKit it is possible to create a navigation view controller with a stack of `UViewController`s.

```
 let nav = UINavigationController()
 nav.viewControllers = [vc1, vc2, vc3]
```

How would you achieve same in `SwiftUI`?

There are navigation buttons that push a view but there is no navigation controller

Comment: SwiftUI has `NavigationView`, but as of Xcode 11 beta 4, we have no way of preloading its stack with multiple views as you do with your `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Add to that, there really is't a `UIViewController`. You can encapsulate(?) it's functionality into a `View`, but to SwiftUI that's all it is. Let's say you are working in `UIKit` and have a need for these three VCs preloaded into a navigation stack - and without using a Storyboard and Segues. The logic behind these VCs... where does *that* go in a "reactive" UI?